# Copy own files to Windows 7 Install USB Flash Drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb

I have a USB flash drive with Windows 7 on (using ISO and the Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool). Now this USB is 16GB and a lot of space available.

Could I copy over a few installer exes and whatnot to my own folder I make on that USB, and install Windows 7 with no problem later or will this corrupt the windows install process/filesystem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

In fact I recommend making an additional folder with drivers so you do not have to insert another disk or pen drive during installation when loading disc drivers.

(Assuming that windows does not already have the right drivers).